# Fuzzy searching with MongoDB, why does /1.0/ match 100.0?

Tags: mongodb

https://imgsa.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=bbcf762fa986c91708035231f93c70c6/10c17c3e6709c93d5eca9c20913df8dcd0005407.jpg

I have implemented fuzzy searching using RegEx as shown below. I just want to get '1.0' and '1.01', But the results show figures such as '1.0' '1.01' '100' '100.10' and '110.11'. Why does 1.0 match 100 and 100.10? How can I only get 1.0 and 1.01?

```
 db.getCollection ("CE").find (
     {
     "ID": /1.0/
     }
    );
```

Comment: Escape the . with \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.` in regex means *any character*, so `1.0` means a `1` followed by `any character`, followed by a `0`. So 100, 1.0 , 1a0, etc are valid matches.

What you need to do is to escape the dot with a `\`. So replace your regex with `1\.0`. Or with `^1\.0` if you want to only match strings that start with `1.0`.

This question has probably been answered many times, please feel free to delete the question.